# JTree não atualiza ao iniciar GUI

Tags: java, swing, gui, jtree

Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo visualizar a solução:

Simplificando, meu programa Java tem uma GUI swing que contém uma JTree (TreeModel customizada para visualização de diretórios do sistema )
Existe um botão para selecionar um diretório  (via JFileChooser), após selecionar a JTree é atualizada e o path desse diretório é armazenado em um arquivo de controle externo (.txt)
Toda vez iniciar o programa, esse arquivo deve ser lido e se existir o caminho. A JTree é populada a partir desse caminho.

Após selecionar via JFileChooser a jTree popula normalmente e a escrita no .txt está ocorrendo. Porém quando tento carregar o caminho a partir do arquivo externo a JTree não está sendo populada. A leitura do arquivo está ocorrendo pois quando mando imprimir no console o valor da variável, o valor do caminho está lá - Exemplo: Se o conteúdo do .txt é C:\testSync\FolderB. 
No construtor da classe GUI após `targetDirectory = new File(synchronizer.readDstFile() );` 
mando imprimir no console `targetDirectory.getPath()`

Quando rodo o programa o console imprime C:\testSync\FolderB . Ou seja o valor na variável que vai pra JTree está certo, o que pode está dando errado??

Classe myGUI:

```
private Synchronizer synchronizer;
private File targetDirectory;
/...

public myGUI(){
    super("SyncBox");
    synchronizer = new Synchronizer();  
    targetDirectory = new File(synchronizer.readDstFile() );
    initGUI();
}

public void initGUI(){
   //...
   subPanelCenter.add( getScrlTargetTree() );
  //...
}

 /**
 * Return the JTree object of the target directory
 * @return JTree - of the target directory
 */
 private JTree getTargetTree() {  
    if (jTreeTarget == null) {  
        targetDirectoryExplorerModel = new DirectoryExplorerModel( targetDirectory );
        jTreeTarget = new JTree( targetDirectoryExplorerModel );
        jTreeTarget.setRootVisible(false);  
        jTreeTarget.setShowsRootHandles(true);  
    }  
    return jTreeTarget;  
 } 


/**
 * Initializing JScrollPane component for target directory
 * It will nest the jTreeTarget
 * */
private JScrollPane getScrlTargetTree() {
    if (jScrlTargetTree == null) {
        jScrlTargetTree = new JScrollPane();
        jScrlTargetTree.setViewportView( getTargetTree() );
    } 
    return jScrlTargetTree;
}

//refresh tree
private void refreshUI() {
    jTreeTarget.setModel(new DirectoryExplorerModel(targetDirectory));
}


/**
* choosing Target Directory (call JFileChooser)
*/
private void chooseTargetDirectory(){
     JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
     fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
     fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(targetDirectory);
     int ret = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
     if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        targetDirectory = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); 
     }
 }
//...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

    if( evt.getSource() == btSelectTargetDirectory ){
        chooseTargetDirectory();
        synchronizer.createControlFileDst(targetDirectory);
        updateTargetPathLabel();
        refreshUI(); //Refresh trees
    }

    //...
}
```

Classe Synchronizer

```
//...

/**
 * Reads the path to Target directory in the control file (.txt)
 * @return String - directory path
 */
public String readDstFile() {
    try {
        File file = new File("ControlFiledst.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = "";
        if (file.exists()){
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(s + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
        }
        String str = sb.toString();
        return str;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Agradeço desde já :)

Comment: Tipo isso? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12697650/4056678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri e resolvi o problema que eu estava tendo

a linha `sb.append(s + "\n");` em `readDstFile()`

O `\n` estava invisivelmente bagunçando a minha formatação da string

Logo, quando chamava `targetDirectory = new File(synchronizer.readDstFile() );` o construtor de `File` não aceitava o padrão. Eu descobri isso mandando imprimir na próxima linha `targetDirectory.exists()`, o qual estava retornando `false`

A solução simplesmente foi `sb.append(s);`